# Hashmap issues, getting exception I don't understand

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` and can't figure out why. I have read a lot of the questions on here and can't seem to dissect anything well enough to get the answers I need. I'm working with a `HashMap` and I'm trying to reference it from a different module.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*; 
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Decoder 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        decrypt();
        keywork(null);
    }

    static void decrypt()
    {
        String codedline = "ilyh wkrxvdqg, wzr kxqguhg dqg qlqhwb-wkuhh".toLowerCase();
        char[] cwarr = codedline.toCharArray();
        String dcline  = "";
        for(char x : cwarr)
        {
            if(Character.isLetter(x))
            {
                int c = (int)x;
                c = c - 3;
                if(c > 90 && c < 97)
                {
                    c += 26;
                }
                x = (char)c;
                dcline += x;
            } else
            {
                dcline += x;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(dcline);
    }

    static void keywork(String dcline)
    {
        int x;
        for(int i = 1, sw = 0; i == dcline.length(); i++)
        {
            String strchk = dcline.substring(sw, i);
            Object n = hm.get(strchk);
        };
    }


    static final HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap <String, Integer>()
    {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2688387173090905196L;
        {
            hm.put("ONE", 1);
            hm.put("TWO", 2);
            hm.put("THREE", 3);
            hm.put("FOUR", 4);
            hm.put("FIVE", 5);
            hm.put("SIX", 6);
            hm.put("SEVEN", 7);
            hm.put("EIGHT", 8);
            hm.put("NINE", 9);
            hm.put("TEN", 10);
            hm.put("ELEVEN", 11);
            hm.put("TWELVE", 12);
            hm.put("THIRTEEN", 13);
            hm.put("FOURTEEN", 14);
            hm.put("FIFTEEN", 15);
            hm.put("SIXTEEN", 16);
            hm.put("SEVENTEEN", 17);
            hm.put("EIGHTEEN", 18);
            hm.put("NINETEEN", 19);
            hm.put("TWENTY", 20);
            hm.put("THIRTY", 30);
            hm.put("FOURTY", 40);
            hm.put("FIFTY", 50);
            hm.put("SIXTY", 60);
            hm.put("SEVENTY", 70);
            hm.put("EIGHTY", 80);
            hm.put("NINETY", 90);
            hm.put("HUNDRED", 100);
            hm.put("THOUSAND", 1000);
        }
    };
}
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at Decoder$1.<init>(Decoder.java:56)
at Decoder.<clinit>(Decoder.java:49)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: Which is line 56?  Which is line 49?  Have you used the debugger to inspect the value of variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never done what you're trying to do so I don't know if it will work the way I think it will, but I can see exactly what's wrong.

You have used an anonymous subclass syntax with your declaration (probably by accident):

```
public static Something object = new Something()
{
    // anonymous subclass declaration here
}
```

The result of that is that, during the initialization of `hm`, you reference it, which (since you're currently running in `hm`'s constructor, is uninitialized.  I'm frankly not even sure how that managed to compile but you should be able to make it work with the following.

```
static final HashMap<String, Integer> hm;

static
{
    hm = new HashMap <String, Integer>()
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2688387173090905196L;
    }
    hm.put("ONE", 1);
    // snip
    hm.put("THOUSAND", 1000);
}
```

Comment: It is actually an idiom that circulates around SO occasionally. There are some cases that really call for it; this is not one of them.

Comment: What issues did you have with method 1?  If it's not correct I'll remove it from my answer.

Answer (score 3):

just remove the "hm" in the static initializer, the hm object does not exist yet! it has to look like this:

```
{
put("ONE", 1);
put("TWO", 2);
put("THREE", 3);
put("FOUR", 4);
put("FIVE", 5);
put("SIX", 6);
put("SEVEN", 7);
put("EIGHT", 8);
put("NINE", 9);
put("TEN", 10);
put("ELEVEN", 11);
put("TWELVE", 12);
put("THIRTEEN", 13);
put("FOURTEEN", 14);
put("FIFTEEN", 15);
put("SIXTEEN", 16);
put("SEVENTEEN", 17);
put("EIGHTEEN", 18);
put("NINETEEN", 19);
put("TWENTY", 20);
put("THIRTY", 30);
put("FOURTY", 40);
put("FIFTY", 50);
put("SIXTY", 60);
put("SEVENTY", 70);
put("EIGHTY", 80);
put("NINETY", 90);
put("HUNDRED", 100);
put("THOUSAND", 1000);
}
```

Comment: i don't think i understand, i removed the hm and get the error under the > saying expecting declaireid, i took everything off and had just what you put... im getting confused.. sorry :(

Comment: the problem is the `keywork(null);`... dcline.length() causes then the NPE because it dcline is null.

Answer (score 2):

This block is an instance initializer:

```
{
/**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2688387173090905196L;
{
    hm.put("ONE", 1);
```

(The double `{{` gives it away). You are trying to access the static `hm` field during its own initialization.

It should work if you remove the `hm.` bit, and just do `put("ONE", 1);` etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something really concise and pure-functional, you should add this code:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> hashMap(Object... data) {
  return fill(new HashMap<K, V>(), data);
}
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> fill(Map<K, V> map, Object... data) {
  if ((data.length & 1) != 0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Odd number of key-value arguments");
  int i = 0;
  while (i < data.length) map.put((K) data[i++], (V) data[i++]);
  return map;
}
```

And then do your initialization like this:

```
public static final Map<Integer, String> hm = hashMap(
  "ONE", 1,
  "TWO", 2,
  "THREE", 3,
  "FOUR", 4,
  "FIVE", 5,
  "SIX", 6,
  "SEVEN", 7,
  "EIGHT", 8,
  "NINE", 9,
  "TEN", 10,
  "ELEVEN", 11,
  "TWELVE", 12,
  "THIRTEEN", 13,
  "FOURTEEN", 14,
  "FIFTEEN", 15,
  "SIXTEEN", 16,
  "SEVENTEEN", 17,
  "EIGHTEEN", 18,
  "NINETEEN", 19,
  "TWENTY", 20,
  "THIRTY", 30,
  "FOURTY", 40,
  "FIFTY", 50,
  "SIXTY", 60,
  "SEVENTY", 70,
  "EIGHTY", 80,
  "NINETY", 90,
  "HUNDRED", 100,
  "THOUSAND", 1000
);
```